# mysql current_timestamp issue in phpMyAdmin openshift db client

Tags: mysql, sql, openshift

When I try to execute this query in openshift phpMyAdmin client I am getting below error:

> #1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

When I was trying to execute below query, I am getting above issue in openshift:

```
`CREATED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`MODIFIED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

But in my local I have HeidiSQL client it is working properly, both in openshift and my local uses same mysql 5.1 version, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I doubt that works given that you have mysql 5.1.Maybe heidi executes the query but quietly ignores the second TIMESTAMP DEFAULT value.

Comment: you might correct, but my problem is that it is not working in even my sql seems correct as per the myphpadmin client error